# Share axes in matplotlib for only part of the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am having a big plot where I initiated with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 4)
```

And I want to do share-x-axis between column 1 and 2; and do the same between column 3 and 4. However, column 1 and 2 does not share the same axis with column 3 and 4.

I was wondering that would there be anyway to do this, and not `sharex=True` and `sharey=True` across all figures?

PS: [This tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) does not help too much, because it is only about sharing x/y within each row/column; they cannot do axis sharing between different rows/columns (unless share them across all axes).

Answer (score 74):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve from your question. However, you can specify per subplot which axis it should share with which subplot when adding a subplot to your figure.

This can be done via:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(5, 4, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(5, 4, 2, sharex = ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(5, 4, 3, sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helps. I looked and it does not seem that there is a method of the axes object that can set the sharex/sharey property. Do you think that's the case?

Comment: I haven't been able to find something so I assume so. I do need to note that my search skills are good but not the best.

Comment: How does it work with axis arrays does ax[1,0] = plot(x,y) ax[1,1] = plot(x,y,sharey=ax[1,0]) . This does not work

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. Don't understand why it is so far down the list. (I guess because it is sorted by Active first).

Comment: It works for axis arrays too - make sure you use `np.empty()` for the array, e.g.: 
    ax = np.empty((4, 2), dtype=object); fig = plt.figure(); ax[0][0] = fig.add_subplot(4, 2, 1, sharex=ax[0][0]);  ax[0][1] = fig.add_subplot(4, 2,  2, sharex=ax[0][0])

Comment: It turns out that `Axes` interface _was_ extended and now [`Axes.sharex`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharex.html) allows to share, e.g.: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(3); ax[2].sharex(ax[1])` to have only the second and third axes to share x. However, graphical rendering seems to be different than using the likes of `plt.subplots(sharex=True)`, in that tick labels are always explicitly rendered and not omitted for contiguous axes (which would require some understanding of contiguity of the axes, here not enforced by `subplots()`).
Tested: matplotlib 3.8.2.

Answer (score 71):

A slightly limited but much simpler option is available for subplots. The limitation is there for a complete row or column of subplots.
For example, if one wants to have common y axis for all the subplots but common x axis only for individual columns in a 3x2 subplot, one could specify it as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharey=True, sharex='col')
```

Comment: This is lovely! Thank you!!

Comment: This really is perfect. Never knew it was a thing until now!

Comment: Really nice feature!

Comment: Perfect! And the equivalent sharey='row'

Answer (score 19):

One can manually manage axes sharing using a `Grouper` object, which can be accessed via `ax._shared_axes['x']` and `ax._shared_axes['y']`. For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def set_share_axes(axs, target=None, sharex=False, sharey=False):
    if target is None:
        target = axs.flat[0]
    # Manage share using grouper objects
    for ax in axs.flat:
        if sharex:
            target._shared_axes['x'].join(target, ax)
        if sharey:
            target._shared_axes['y'].join(target, ax)
    # Turn off x tick labels and offset text for all but the bottom row
    if sharex and axs.ndim > 1:
        for ax in axs[:-1,:].flat:
            ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labelbottom=False, labeltop=False)
            ax.xaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
    # Turn off y tick labels and offset text for all but the left most column
    if sharey and axs.ndim > 1:
        for ax in axs[:,1:].flat:
            ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', labelleft=False, labelright=False)
            ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 4)
set_share_axes(axs[:,:2], sharex=True)
set_share_axes(axs[:,2:], sharex=True)
```

To adjust the spacing between subplots in a grouped manner, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820618/pylab-adjust-hspace-for-some-of-the-subplots).

EDIT: Modified the code according to the latest matplotlib API updates. Thanks to @Jonvdrdo 's suggestions!

Comment: Not directly applicable at my use case (sharing x-axis between row 2n and row 2n+1, and sharing y-axis of all even-numbered rows on the one hand, and all odd-numbered rows on the other hand, for an 8 rows by 2 columns figure), but I could adapt it. I didn't know of `Grouper`, nice!

Comment: The Matplotlib API has been updated, see [this link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/710fce3df95e22701bd68bf6af2c8adbc9d67a79/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L4747-L4749). As a result, you need to change the `if sharex` content to `target._shared_axes['x'].join(target, ax)` and `if sharey` to `target._shared_axes['y'].join(target, ax)`. Then it works for later Matplotlib versions (tested on Matplotlib==3.5.1)

Comment: Note: In the past (<3.8) one could also access the `target._shared_axes['x']` and `target._shared_axes['y']` via `get_shared_x_axes()` and `get_shared_y_axes()`, which, imho, looks better than using the "private" methods. BUT now these return immutable `GrouperView` objects. So you need to either go the way of `target._shared_axes` or target.get_shared_x_axes()._grouper` . I am not sure what they (at mpl) were thinking here.

Answer (score 4):

I used Axes.sharex /sharey in a similar setting

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharex.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharex

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic([list(range(3))] +[['A']*3, ['B']*3])

axd[0].plot([0,0.2])
axd['A'].plot([1,2,3])
axd['B'].plot([1,2,3,4,5])


axd['B'].sharex(axd['A'])

for i in [1,2]:
    axd[i].sharey(axd[0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer since they have deprecated the `.join()` function for `get_shared_x_axes` in matplotlib 3.6